# Leak in updating label

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm new to tkinter and have traced a memory leak in a project I'm doing down to a clock in my code. It turns out the memory leak happens when updating a label, the simplest example I've got it down to in code is:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Display:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'a')
        self.label.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.master.after(50, self.tick)

root = tk.Tk()
disp = Display(root)
```

If somebody could tell me why this leaks memory I'd be grateful.

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are creating Labels without destroying them.  Each time you create a new label and place it over the old one, so it is still being referenced and thus can't be garbage collected.

Here is a slightly revised version that doesn't leak....

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Display:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.label = None
        self.master = master
        self.tick()

    def tick(self):
        if self.label:
            self.label.destroy()
        self.label = tk.Label(self.master, text = 'a')
        self.label.place(x=0,y=0)
        self.master.after(50, self.tick)

root = tk.Tk()
disp = Display(root)
```

Comment: while this does answer the question, it's an inefficient solution. There's no reason to delete and recreate the widget if all you're doing is changing the text.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `tick` keeps creating new labels. There's no reason to create more than one label in a loop like this unless you really do need an ever increasing number of labels. You can update the text of a label widget by using the `configure` method.

For example:

```
def tick(self):
    self.label.configure(text=`my new text`)
    self.after(50, self.tick)
```