# Tkinter Canvas Update Memory Leak

Tags: python, canvas, memory-leaks, tkinter

I'm seeing a memory leak in the code below. I'm creating and processing my data in separate modules, but this isn't causing the leak from what I can see. I believe it's because I am calling a new instance of drawing class each time I change my scale, although I'm not sure how to correct this issue. I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8468198), but when I try and implement `self.canvas.destroy()` method on my code I receive an error. I was wondering what method could be applied to the code below to solve my issue?

**Code Snippet:**

```
from Tkinter import *

class Interface_On:

    def Interface_Elements(self, master):
        self.master=master
        self.master.title( "My Canvas")
        self.c=Canvas(self.master, width=1000, height=1000, bg='black')
        self.c.grid(row=0, column=0)
        menubar = Menu(master)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.Edit_New)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
        master.config(menu=menubar)
        drawing_utility_run=Drawing_Utility()
        drawing_utility_run.drawer(self.c)

    def Edit_New(self): 
        Export_Poscar = self.Export_Poscar = Toplevel(self.master)
        self.Export_Poscar.title('New Ribbon...')
        self.Export_Poscar.geometry('300x400')
        self.scale_Label= Label(Export_Poscar, width=15, text='scale:')
        self.scale_Label.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.scale_Label= Label(Export_Poscar, width=15, text='scale:')
        scale_var = StringVar()
        self.scale_Spin= Spinbox(Export_Poscar, from_=1, to=1000, increment=1, width=15, command=self.execute_request_immediate, textvariable=scale_var)
        self.scale_Spin.grid(row=2, column=2)

    def execute_request_immediate(self):
        global scale
        User_Set_Scale=float(self.scale_Spin.get())
        scale=User_Set_Scale
        drawing_utility_run=Drawing_Utility()
        drawing_utility_run.drawer(self.c)

class Drawing_Utility:
    def drawer(self, canvas):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.canvas.delete('all')
        import Generator #generates my data (imports 'scale' from above where possible)
        Generator_run=Generator.Generator()
        Generator_run.generator_go()        
        from Generator import coordinates_x_comp, coordinates_y_comp #imports necessary lists
        import Processor #Imports coordinates_x_comp, coordinates_y_comp, cleans and analyses
        Process_xy_Data=Processor.Data_Processor()
        Process_xy_Data.Process_Data()
        from Processor import p_1, p_2
        for Line in xrange(len(p_1)):
            self.canvas.create_line(p_1[Line],p_2[Line], fill='red', activefill='blue', width=1)

root=Tk()
run_it_canvas=Interface_On()
run_it_canvas.Interface_Elements(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What error do you get when you use `self.canvas.destroy()`?

Comment: TclError: invalid command name ".4315986616"

Comment: @Brionius, can nested key bindings within a canvas class cause memory issues?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure any of these things will fix the memory leak you say you're observing, but there are a few issues I'd fix that might help:

1. You're using a local variable (`drawing_utility_run`) to store your `Drawing_Utility` instances. It's not entirely clear why those instances aren't getting garbage collected once the method they were created in exits, but either way, it seems like you probably want that object to persist, so you should store the reference in the instance namespace, like this:

```
self.drawing_utility_run=Drawing_Utility()
self.drawing_utility_run.drawer(self.c)
```

2. When you delete all canvas objects with `self.canvas.delete('all')` you're relying on the fact that your Tkinter version implements the string `'all'` as a recognized constant, which may be the case, but isn't guaranteed.  The `Canvas.delete` function will accept any argument, whether it represents a recognized constant or an tag/ID or not, without throwing an error - for example try `self.canvas.delete('blah blah blah')`.  I.e. you're banking on `self.canvas.delete('all')` deleting all objects, but it's not obvious to me that it does so.  Use the `Tkinter` constant `ALL` instead of the string `'all'`.

3. Unless you have a very good reason for having your imported modules only exist in the `Drawing_Utility` instance namespace, you should move all the `import` statements to the top, in the module-level namespace.

4. Your import statements are redundant:

```
import Generator #generates my data (imports 'scale' from above where possible)
from Generator import coordinates_x_comp, coordinates_y_comp #imports necessary lists
import Processor #Imports coordinates_x_comp, coordinates_y_comp, cleans and analyses
from Processor import p_1, p_2
```

You don't need to both `import Generator` and `from Generator import coordinates_x_comp`.  Just `import Generator` then refer to `Generator.coordinates_x_comp`.  By using both import statements, you're double-importing `Generator.coordinates_x_comp`, `Processor.p_1` etc.

Comment: You wrote "...you're relying on the fact that your Tkinter version implements the string 'all' as a recognized constant, which may be the case, but isn't guaranteed. " that is mot true. Tk has supported `"all”` for a couple of decades, and takes backwards compatibility _very_ seriously. There is absolutely no chance the constant string `"all"` will stop working in the foreseeable future.

Comment: Just because it works, and probably will keep working, doesn't make it a good programming practice.

Comment: in this specific case, I disagree. It's more likely that the Tkinter maintainers will decide to remove or rename the `ALL` constant in a future version of Tkinter than it is that `"all"` will case to work.

Comment: Interesting - if that's the case, why would the `Tkinter` authors have bothered with `ALL` in the first place?  Why not hard-code the `"all"` string into the module?  I understand that this is how `Tk` works, but I don't see why the `Tkinter` maintainers would make that decision.

Comment: I have no idea what they were thinking when they made constants for constant literal strings in Tk -- it seems pointless to me. I can only guess they were trying to hide the underlying implementation, but I can't think of a valid reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've implemented your advice and I am seeing an improvement in run time and marginally reduced memory usage. However, I'm still seeing between 5 and 10MB of memory being used with each alteration of the scale, which poses no issues for a few dozen alterations, but rapidly creates problems if I make hundreds or thousands of alterations (which is a potential requirement). I've also made small test program to run the back end data stuff without the UI and there is no leak at all... Are there any methods to clear/check which component is causing the leak?

Comment: @MarkyD43 Well, every time you change the scale, you call `execute_request_immediate`, which is pretty innocuous except that it calls `Drawing_Utility.drawer`, which imports a bunch of stuff from your other modules, and uses methods in those other modules.  I'm not sure what makes you think the memory is not being used up by those other modules, but it certainly seems likely to me.

Comment: @Brionius I explained that poorly, apologies. I meant that while memory is being used by the other modules, each time I call the data modules _without_ the UI/Canvas component, the memory is released and then reused, whereas when run in conjunction with the UI/Canvas the memory is never released until I quit the program. This is what's leading me to believe the issue lies with the canvas rather than the other modules.